# WCF SetCertificate: how is it used

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl, ssl-certificate, self-hosting

I hava a self-hosted wcf service which is configured for ssl.
The certifiacate is bound to the port of the service by commandline,
using the 'netsh' command, e.g.:

*netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:8000 certhash=XYZ appid={"ABC"}*

This is described here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms733791(v=vs.110).aspx.
It works as expeced.

Now I just discovered that there is a **SetCertificate-Method:**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.servicemodel.description.servicecredentials.servicecertificate(v=vs.110).aspx

So, I thought I can make use of this method, and do not need the netsh comamnd
for binding the certifiacte anymore. 
But it does not work? SetCertificate seems to have no effect?
So what else is it used for? 
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I can answer my own question. Found the answer here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms789011(v=vs.110).aspx

- **If the transport is HTTP** (using the WSHttpBinding), SSL over HTTP provides the transport-level security. In that case, you must configure the computer hosting the service with an SSL certificate bound to a port, as shown later in this topic.
- **If the transport is TCP** (using the NetTcpBinding), by default the transport-level security provided is Windows security, or SSL over TCP. When using SSL over TCP, you must specify the certificate using the SetCertificate method, as shown later in this topic.

So the SetCertificate method is only used when Transport is TCP. In my case it is Http, so I have to bind the Certificate to the port manually as I did.